# How do I add unique page titles and meta titles to paginated views pages?

Tags: views, taxonomy-terms, 7

I have overridden the taxonomy term pages with a view, and I want to be able to set the page title, both visible and meta, with unique titles for each page within the pager for SEO purposes. I am hoping the solution resides in a module, or in a view setting (and not on a template basis).

Do you have any suggestion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are actually two modules:

- the [Meta tags](http://drupal.org/project/metatag) module that is used to add meta tags to any pages

  > The Meta tags module allows you to automatically provide structured metadata about your website. In the context of search engine optimization, when people refer to meta tags, they are usually referring to the meta description tag and the meta keywords tag that may help improve the rankings and display of your site in search engine results.
- the [Page Title](http://drupal.org/project/page_title) module that is used to set the title visible with the `<title>` tag

  > This module gives you granular control over the page title. You can specify patterns for how the title should be structured and, on content creation pages, specify the page title separately to the content's title.
- the [Title Overrides](http://drupal.org/project/title_override) module

  > Title Overrides is a module to provide title overrides for any page in as simple as an interface as possible. This module differs from the Page Title module in that this overrides both the `<title>` meta tag as well as the `<h1>` tag. You also have the option of entirely removing the page title from any page, which will remove the `<h1>` tags as well as remove the piping from the meta title. This improves search engine optimization for pages that have been overridden.

As far as I recall, there were some problems using the Meta tags module to set meta tags for views, but it can be they have been resolved, now.

The Title Overrides module seems the one you are looking for, as it overrides the content's title for any page.